# BillingGeocodeAccuracy - missing field error

Tags: apex, api, integration

We are receiving below error only in PROD but not Sandbox when we query Account from Boomi connector. Also our Boomi Integrations are up and running since 2 years. It never errored before and suddenly from a deployment a week ago, it started erroring. Any idea why?

> "No such column 'BillingGeocodeAccuracy' on entity 'Account'. If you
> are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
> after the custom field name."

Comment: What does it show when you run `SELECT BillingStateCode FROM Account` in developer console

Comment: Billing State codes are retrieved.

Comment: Looks related to the known issue https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008g2IQAQ. Can you try the workaround mentioned in KI to see if that fixes the error

Comment: No our case is different! Our Boomi connector is querying individual fields, not a compound field.